# Truncated output from CFB mode when calling from C#

Tags: c#, c++, encryption, pinvoke, crypto++

I have pretty annoying issue which I'm unable to solve for 2 days. I have an `encrypt()` method which makes use of Crypto++ library written in C++. The method is implemented as follows:

```
string CRijndaelHelper::Encrypt(string text)
{
    CFB_Mode< AES >::Encryption e;
    e.SetKeyWithIV(_key, sizeof(_key), _iv);

    string cipher, encoded;

    // CFB mode must not use padding. Specifying
    //  a scheme will result in an exception
    StringSource ss(text, true,
        new StreamTransformationFilter(e,
            new StringSink(cipher)
        ));     

    return cipher;
};
```

When I call this method within the native environment it works perfectly, encrypting the whole 26Kb xml string without any problem.

Eventually I've had to implement the encryption in C# code, for that purpose I wrote the following wrapper code in native dll for later use with PInvoke:

```
extern "C"
API_EXPORT char* _cdecl encrypt(char* contents)
{   
    string cont(contents);
    CRijndaelHelper rij;
    string transformedText = rij.Encrypt(cont);     
    return marshalReturn(transformedText);  
}
```

While the PInvoke part looks as follows:

```
[DllImport("EncryptDecrypt.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
public static extern string encrypt([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string contents);
```

And everything looks working perfect except that I get in `transformedText` variable only first 540 bytes encrypted and that's all.

Please advise.

Comment: Just guessing, but `rij.Encrypt(cont)` probably returns an array with a 0x00 byte around position 540. Encypted text should be evenly distributed over [0-255], so there should be lots of then in 26KB. The fix is to change the return value from a `char*` to something that includes a length.

Comment: Its probably better to redisgn that interface with `API_EXPORT int _cdecl encrypt(IN unsigned char* in, OUT unsigned char* out, INOUT unsigned int* osize)`.

Comment: The whole point is that rij.Encrypt() successfully receives xml string and returns a string which is correctly encrypted when invoked from native code. The CryptoPP supports StringSink target as you can see from code. The whole question is what happens with PInvoke call that affects the API.

Comment: I can tell you for certain that `StreamTransformationFilter(e, new StringSink(cipher))` is going to have a `NULL` embedded in it eventually. The `string` will deal with it OK since a C++ string has the C character array *and* a length; a `char*` will not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... returns a string which is correctly encrypted when invoked from native code

The problem is not you C++ `encrypt`, which uses a `std::string`. The problem is with marshalling it back to managed code as a `char*`.

Change `CRijndaelHelper::Encrypt` to the following to remove the embedded `NULL` that will be sprinkled liberally with a probability of 1/255:

```
#include <cryptopp/base64.h>
using CryptoPP::Base64Encoder;
...

string CRijndaelHelper::Encrypt(string text)
{
    CFB_Mode< AES >::Encryption e;
    e.SetKeyWithIV(_key, sizeof(_key), _iv);

    string cipher, encoded;

    // CFB mode must not use padding. Specifying
    //  a scheme will result in an exception
    StringSource ss(text, true,
        new StreamTransformationFilter(e,
            new Base64Encoder(
                new StringSink(cipher)
        )));     

    return cipher;
};
```

With the `Base64` encoding, the marshaling as a `char*` will *not* truncate the encryption results on the first `NULL` byte encountered.

Then, for decryption:

```
StringSource ss(cipher, true,
    new Base64Decoder(
        new StreamTransformationFilter(d,
            new StringSink(text)
    )));
```

Comment: You're the man! :) Works now. Would never catch this I think without help. The only thing I struggle to understand is what the actual difference between std::string constructed natively and std::string initialized with char* array marshaled from CLR. What marshalling actually does to this char* that causes encryption to fail? In fact, it occurs well before marshaling back to managed.

Answer (score 2):

Your fundamental problem is that you are working on the wrong types. Encryption works with byte arrays and not with text. You need to stop using `string`, `char*` and so on. You need to use `unsigned char*` in the unmanaged code, and `byte[]` in the managed code.

It might be hard for you to accept this advice, but I proffer it all the same. On top of the problems with zero bytes being treated as null terminators (the reason for your truncation), your current approach simply neglects the issue of text encoding. You cannot do that.

You presumably have good reasons why you wish to transform a string to another string. That's fine, but the encryption part of the transformation needs to operate on byte arrays. The way to handle encryption of text to text is to use a chain of transformations. The transformation when encrypting runs like this:

1. Convert string to byte array using well-defined encoding. For instance, UTF-8.
2. Encrypt byte array, which results in another byte array being output.
3. Encode this encrypted byte array as text using, for example, base64.

This respects the fact that encryption operates on byte arrays, as well as being explicit about the text encoding.

In the opposite direction you reverse the steps:

1. Decode the base64 to an encrypted byte array.
2. Decrypt this byte array.
3. Decode the decrypted byte array using UTF-8 to obtain the original string.

Comment: Agree with you David but unfortunately there are a lot of files being in use by company which are already encrypted with this exact approach so I'm afraid changing the encoding might cause problems. The CRijndaelHelper::Encrypt() code was written well before I started my implementation. However, the JWW's approach above, supported by your answer has helped me a lot. Thanks!

Comment: The answer that you accepted suggests a change in approach, not vastly different to what I suggest. What the other answer does not address is the possibility of encountering non-ASCII text.

Comment: That's exactly what I meant to say.

Comment: @aquila - David is right about the design issues. I only helped with a very narrow issue (the embedded `NULL` causing truncation). You still have larger issues that should be addressed. While David suggested UTF-8, I'd say you *must* use it for portability.

Comment: @jww Thanks for the generous comment. I'd say that UTF8 is not the only possible choice. Although it is very likely the best. Some times UTF16 might be best. However, the key is that the encoding used to go from text to byte array (and back) is well defined in an explicit way.

Comment: @David - Wei uses the `std::string` like an SGI [`Rope`](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Rope.html). Its definitely not a character array in the common sense. Its very confusing, and it has room for improvement. Lots of folks have complained over the years. But you are right - a `vector` should be used instead. I *think* Wei wanted concatenation and substring operations on the `Rope`, and that's why he chose `string`.