# PDF Corrupted after AES encryption using Crypto++

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, aes, crypto++

I'm trying to encrypt pdf using AES algorithm of crypto++ library in an android app. the program takes a pdf file and creates a new encrypted file. and while decryption it takes an encrypted file, and creates a new decrypted file.

but problem is, when I'm encrypting a pdf, the original file becomes corrupted. other applications cannot open the original file. the decrypted one is also corrupted. however .txt files work perfectly well in both encryption and decryption and the original file is also ok.

Here is the code...

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "aes.h"
#include "files.h"
#include "modes.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace CryptoPP;

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

byte key[AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH];
byte iv[AES::BLOCKSIZE];


void encrypt(char* inputFile, char* out) {
    AES::Encryption aesEncryption(key, AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH);
    CBC_Mode_ExternalCipher::Encryption cbcEncryption(aesEncryption, iv);

    FileSource f(inputFile, true, new StreamTransformationFilter(cbcEncryption, new FileSink(out)));
}

void decrypt(char* in, char* out) {
    AES::Decryption aesDecryption(key, AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH);
    CBC_Mode_ExternalCipher::Decryption cbcDecryption(aesDecryption, iv);

    FileSource f(in, true, new StreamTransformationFilter(cbcDecryption, new FileSink(out)));
}

jstring Java_com_onik_encryptedpdf_MainActivity_test(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj) {
    string ret = "NDK OK 5 Encryption Complete!";

    memset(key, 0x00, AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH);
    memset(iv, 0x00, AES::BLOCKSIZE);


    //encrypt("sdcard/t.txt", "sdcard/tEnc.enc");
    decrypt("sdcard/tEnc.enc", "sdcard/tDec.txt");

    return env->NewStringUTF(ret.c_str());
}

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Whats the problem here... Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: This will not work reliably: ***`encrypt(char* inputFile, char* out)`*** and ***`decrypt(char* in, char* out)`*** because of embedded NULL characters. You are making the same mistakes detailed in [Truncated output from CFB mode when calling from C#](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24237654); you're just doing it in a different language. Also, mobile devices are resource constrained, so you have to be careful about the way you use memory. You can't always load a large PDF, MP3 or MP4 file into memory and operate on it. You have to process the data in blocks.

Comment: Be careful of this: ***`encrypt("sdcard/t.txt", "sdcard/tEnc.enc");`*** because the SD card effectively has `MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE` when an application holds `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` (which many of them request). You should add a MAC to detect tampering.